# OpenVPNd routing and forwarding

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to setup an OpenVPN daemon on my network, but have some issues with iptables + routing.

Here's a glimpse of my config:
- current LAN is on 192.168.2.0/24, OpenVPN daemon runs on 192.168.2.251

The daemon starts just fine, but whenever I initiate a connection from clients, I see those messages:

```
Mon Feb  5 17:41:59 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Mon Feb  5 17:41:59 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
Mon Feb  5 17:41:59 2018 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.2.251/32 dev br0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mon Feb  5 17:41:59 2018 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Mon Feb  5 17:41:59 2018 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Mon Feb  5 17:41:59 2018 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Mon Feb  5 17:41:59 2018 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5
```

First off, why the error status 2, and second, why do I see route add when push route is commented in the daemon's server.conf ?

That's one part of the issue, the other part is I do not know how to "merge" new iptables rules to my current iptables rules ?
I currently have these rules, in this order (main NIC is eth0, openvpn's is tun0):

```
$IPT -F INPUT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
<some other rules>
# VPNd rules
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1199 -j ACCEPT #openVPNd runs on udp/1199
$IPT -A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
<some other rules>
```

net.ipv4.forwarding = 1 is set in /etc/sysctl.conf

Now, one of the effect of my misbehaving rules is that a client connecting on the vpn server cannot connect on servers outside my lan (192.168.2.0/24). I'd want my clients to be able to connect anywhere they chose, from my vpn link.

I just noticed that the error messages above seem to show up only on client hosts that use bridged networking (some of my clients are also KVM hypervisors). On OSX, for instances, and my VMs, it does not show up. Is there a link ?

What am I missing ?

iptables -vL output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 3975  963K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    5   308 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
    6   492 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:dmidi
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:grcp
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:25826
 2198  432K REJECT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1552 packets, 225K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    tun0    anywhere             anywhere
```

iptables -t nat -VL output:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

(empty ?)

VPN daemon's ip addr output:
    [19:28:50|jfgratton@vpntst:~]: ip addr

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:5f:f8:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.251/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast 
state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

All clients are on the same /24 (192.168.2.0) . Two of the clients, while being on the same subnet, use bridged interfaces (br0 instead of a physical one such as eth0); I do not think it's important, but I want to leave no stone unturned, so to speak.

### NEW OUTPUT:

```
[20:00:45|root@vpntst:~]: iptables -vL;iptables -t nat -vL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  212 17577 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:dmidi
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:grcp
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:25826
   13  2621 REJECT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 144 packets, 16717 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    tun0    anywhere             anywhere
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 20 packets, 3509 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 912 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 912 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    10.8.0.0/24          anywhere
```

And my firewall script :
    #!/bin/bash
    IPT=/sbin/iptables

```
case "$1" in
start)
$IPT -F INPUT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
# VPNd rules
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1199 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

# Other rules
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 9123 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 25826 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -j REJECT
exit 0
;;
stop)
$IPT -F INPUT
exit 0
;;

* )
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/firewall {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
```

Now, I've taken the instructions to setup a vpnd from https://chichivica.github.io/2017/08/02/Install-OpenVPN-on-Fedora-26/ . I now realize that there's no mention of routing or anything out there. One thing I did that I was sure it was needed is to enable ipv4 forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf. Otherwise I strictly followed the instructions on that link, nothing else.

### SERVER.CONF

Here's my routing config in server.conf. I even tried a few minutes ago to comment out the last push, same result, unfortunately:

```
[9:03:07|root@vpntst:openvpn]: egrep "route|redirect" server.conf|egrep -v ^\#
;push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

This one drives me nuts :-)

Comment: What's the output of `iptables -vL` and `iptables -t nat -vL`?

Comment: @TorinCarey just added the output in my original post (... looks like I'm no good with serverfault's MD !! :) )

Comment: Your setup is a bit confusing in terms of which networks you are on about. Could you also add `ip address`?

Comment: Posted in OP, again, with a client's ip addr output as well

Comment: Assuming that hosts on the LAN are not aware that 192.168.2.251 is the next-hop for 10.8.0.0/24, then you will need to translate the source address of packets originating from the tunnel interface. You would want something along the lines of `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`.

Comment: Same result, I'm afraid. I've added new output under the section "New output" of the OP (I'm afraid I still s*ck at serverfault's markdown)

Comment: «whenever I initiate a connection from clients, I see those messages»—do you see them on the server or on the clients?

Comment: @kostix tjose messages show up client-side. As I mentioned, I do mot see them everywhere (osx does not),  but I can't figure why, all push directives are commented in server.conf

Comment: Please raise the debug level on the misbehaving clients and verify there is really no mentions of the push directives (they are logged).

Comment: @kostix I've pasted the connection log (verbosity = 5) at https://gist.github.com/jeanfrancoisgratton/61501783385eacbcc9bf56f820035e48

This is from the kvm hypervisor I might use to establish a client VPN connection from, 192.168.2.8/24 . The server is on 192.168.2.251.
Once the connection established, 192.168.2.8 is unable to route traffic outside (the internet). If I connect from another machine (say, 192.168.2.5) to 192.168.2.8 (thus not to the VPNd), same thing.

Comment: I might just use some dockerized openvpnd image existing in the docker registry, but I'd really like to understand and fix it myself. More challenge and learning there. Your help everyone is much appreciated.

Comment: I beleive that's the `redirect-gateway` parameter. The client instance tries to redirect its default GW and executes `route add 192.168.2.251/32 dev br0`. Do you really need that? In most cases, you should left the default GW as is.

Comment: See section SERVER.CONF in OP, I cannot format the output properly here, @kostix

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a non-answer, really. I cannot go any further on this as I need to add static routes on my outgoing router, which my ISP prevents me to do.

Case closed until I change ISP